# Future dating discount coupons in Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

We have a monthly subscription for $450/month but we will sometimes charge customers a pre-opening rate of $150/month until they open their restaurant.  In addition to this, we have sales promotions where a customer might get $50 off their monthly rate.  We also charge for the first month at the time of sign-up to reserve their resources.  I can't find a way to achieve this in Stripe systematically.

For example:
Customer signs up for a $450 dollar plan on January 1, 2018 and receives a $50 lifetime monthly discount.  They will not open their doors until July 1, 2018.

Desired billing would be:

1. Jan 1: $400 (prepayment of first month's service)

   Feb 1: $150+$500 (pre-opening rate + one-time clean-up fee)

   Mar 1: $150

   Apr 1: $150

   May 1: $150

   Jun 1: $150

   Jul 1: $0 (prepaid on Jan 1)

   Aug 1: $400 (go-forward standard plan rate)

   Sep 1: $400

   ...

My desire is to create a systematic way to automate this payment flow.
I'm not sure how to achieve it without manually updating the discounts each month.

Stripe does not allow multiple coupons on one subscription, and they don't allow multiple subscriptions with different start dates (that I can tell).  These were our two best ideas on how to achieve what we're after.

Can anyone help, please?